# Library / Book Lending Software

Tags: information-management, sharepoint, books

I'm looking for a software package to manage lending physical books, and potentially other physical items such as computer hardware, optical disks, or tools.

**Requirements**

- Accessible by at least 100 users via web interface
- Check in and check out books, etc and keep track of who has them and history of lending
- Internet-facing (not intranet only)
- Doesn't have to be free but should have a demo if we need to pay for it.
- No real requirements for what the server is hosted on, we have cloud accounts and can spin something up as needed.

**Nice to Haves**

- SharePoint integration
- If no SharePoint integration, should be able to authenticate against Active Directory

I have seen [another question here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/book-management-software-for-library) but my requirements differ, mainly that I am looking for SharePoint integration and users to be able to "self-checkout" rather, from what I can ascertain LibLime Koha does require a centralized system.