# Digital Library / File Management

Tags: file-management, ebooks, information-management, books

Similar to [this question with an answer recommending Koha](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/book-management-software-for-library/2718#2718) and [my own question about library / book lending software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/library-book-lending-software), but with vastly different requirements.

**Requirements**

- Accessible by at least 75 users via web interface.
- Download PDF documents, MP3 music files, Word documents, Power Point Documents, MP4 video and audio files, FLV videos, possibly other electronic formats.
- Internet-facing, web-accessible
- Only accessible by authorizes users
- No real requirements for what the server is hosted on, we have cloud accounts and can spin something up as needed.
- Email Communications. Emails sent to confirm download (or "thanks for downloading") and emails sent periodically asking users to review past downloads (possibly weekly, for all the things they downloaded that week, for instance)
- Track who downloaded the files

It seems like SharePoint would handle this quite well (and my team is leaning toward tracking this on our SharePoint instance within Office 365). Unfortunately I do not have access to our SharePoint so I can't just fire it up and try it. My main concerns with using SharePoint is the ability to audit who is downloading what, and the email communication requirement. I have no idea if SharePoint can easily be configured to trigger emails, or to what extent it can do so if that is possible.