# Web based, userfriendly and open source "stuff" managing system

Tags: open-source, web-apps, document-management, books

I'm searching for a small web based (dockerized if possible) and open source (git{hub|lab}) system for managing `<stuff>` in a small association (~money-less so we have to built it on our own and nobody is really versed into the digital world so it has to be user friendly for both its installation and its final usage), especially their borrowing state information (who, when, return date).

I've browsed the site and more broadly on the Internet, but all what I found was desktop applications which are probably far more complex that what I would need. Based on [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39255/simple-and-free-book-library-management-system-ils-for-a-small-library) thread, [Koha](https://koha-community.org/) seems to be the closest candidate but it also seems way too complex for our needs.

Some of the needs are:

- expected number of `<stuff>` items (min-max) [ 100-1000 ]
- expected number of users (min-max) [ 100-1000 ]
- for the moment `<stuff>` = books, but it will probably be enlarged to other type of material in the future
- a web based public interface to see which books are borrowed (and in that case show their date of return) / available
- super simple and user friendly to install, manage and use (as I said, some persons are not really familiar with the digital world)
- user auth (not a priority)
- an admin interface to manage state of the `<stuff>` and to see more information (e.g. who borrows) (not a priority as I guess it fully depends on the presence of an authentication process with rights separation)

Comment: I'm looking for a similar thing, cant believe i didnt find your post before making mine: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77750/personal-library-catalog-like-software-for-keeping-track-of-physical-media?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest taking a look at the various resources here:
[list-open-source-software-for-resource-scheduling-and-booking](https://edgeryders.eu/t/list-open-source-software-for-resource-scheduling-and-booking/6629)

There are a couple of systems that can be adapted for your purposes e.g.

- [Leihs](https://github.com/leihs/leihs) - if you can think of a book as "equipment"...
- [Reservations](https://github.com/YaleSTC/reservations)